# Android icon is much smaller than other icons after using Android SDK tool?

Tags: android, graphics

Here is a image of my android icon for the app Contak (in red) compared to some other icons: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/n4oa5mY.jpg]. My image was failing to upload to imgur, so sorry I couldn't embed.

My icon is a decent amount smaller than other icons and it bothers me somewhat. I saw other questions where people put wrong sized icons in the drawable folders, but I used the new built in SDK tool and put -10% on padding so it shouldn't have an error.

I also added:`<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>` into my app. Any ideas what's up? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Documentation on Iconography](https://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) for details. I assume that the SDK tool left some padding around your icon. 
Open the MDPI icon (which should be 48x48 px) and see if there is transparent pixels around. If yes, then you might want to enlarge the icon a bit to cover the whole 48x48 px.

Comment: Yes, there is a bit of a transparent border with the build in sdk tool. I Found a new tool http://makeappicon.com/download/34c60acbf8f4425d96e3ff905e7217fa# that doesn't have one! Thanks!